# SBT dependencyOverrides in a scope doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: sbt

I would like to have a different version of library in test scope.

I was hoping the simplified version of project descriptor could look like that.
Please mind it's a simplified view, in my real project it's more convoluted. I need to use `dependencyOverrides` to enforce certain library version.

```
import sbt._, Keys._

organization :=  "me"
name := "test"
version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies := Seq("ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3")

dependencyOverrides := Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.2"
)

dependencyOverrides in Test := Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.1"
)
```

I'd be hoping to see `logback-classic` version `1.2.1` when I run:
`show test:managedClasspath`.
Instead I get `logback-classic` version `1.2.2` as if `dependencyOverrides in Test` was ignored.

At the same time when I run `show Test/dependencyOverrides` I get the expected result which is:

```
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1
```

Does anyone has a clue what am I missing in the relation between `dependencyOverrides` in `Test` scope and `managedClasspath`?

Comment: (I deleted my answer since it wasn't helpful)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem cannot be solve the way I imagined. The main reason is `libraryDependencies` and `update` [are not scoped to configuration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5669).

I think the best solution is in case I need a different version of library in some tests to extract those tests to a separate module with independent set of `libraryDependencies`.